# SQL query allowing a drop down list of the columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to have a drop down list populate based on the values that are in the specific column that a user could then select?

i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE Products.Color = //Drop down list that is populated based on the values in the column.
```

So after this would be run it would pop up a drop down list for the user to select which value they are looking for and then a table would populate based on what was selected from the list

Is this possible?

EDIT :

So right now I could type

SELECT * FROM Products
    WHERE Products.Color = <<>>

This would give the user a field, where they would be able to enter the color they are looking for and then a table would show with all the products that had that color.

I'm curious if there was a way to instead have a field where they are able to select a color from the values that have already been entered into the Products.Color column?

Comment: What is your drop down list being created in? This isn't really a SQL question  (from a sql standpoint, answer = yes...you can put a color in your where clause and have it return the rows you need).

Comment: you are going to have to give more details and be more specific. What dropdown list? What code is calling the database. How is that code called. It's hard for people to understand what you're trying to do, that you've done and that problems you've had.

Comment: Questions like this are most easily answered if you can provide an example of all the tables involved, listing the column names and a few example rows.

Comment: K, change my answer then. No it is not possible to create a drop down list in SQL because SQL is not a GUI creating language...it's a query language. your edit of ":EDIT : So right now I could type " does not answer the question...what are you typing that into?  What are you creating this drop down box with?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you want the output to be a list of colors or you want to customize the query to choose from multiple colors. I'll try answering both.

1. If you want to choose from more than one value, you could change your query to:

   ```
   select * from products
   where products.color in ('Red', 'Blue'...);
   ```
2. If you want to just select all colors from the table, which you would then use to populate a drop down list (say, in VB) :

   ```
   select distinct color
   from products;
   ```

Hope this helps.